# Typescript interface extends React.FC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to extend `React.FC` with custom interface like this:

```
interface IComponent<P = {}> extends React.FC {
  custom?: {a: string, b: string};
}

const Page:IComponent<{text: string}> = ({text}) => (
  <>{text}</>
)

Page.custom = {a: '1', b: '2'}
```

`Page.custom` is typed correctly, but `React.FC` props functionality is lost. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured that out. I needed to pass `P` param from `IComponent` to `React.FC`

```
interface IComponent<P = {}> extends React.FC<P> {
  custom?: {a: string, b: string};
}
```

Comment: see here https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIDs4DkUqGBAsAFCXC4xJSbpJwCSAwhOHkrQDwAKcALxwA3gF8AfHCQAPOrgAmAZ0QkYAOgBibOAMmjKcOGgCuymJwD8ALjEo7FqDQDmAGjgAjRzGe4X4gDclOKUYRRoeBZw-CguSACMNuyckLg8MLyidPI+fgHSIgAU2XIw4gCUwtJFRnoGOeW8APSSlBXhlJG40bHxAEzJHFzpfKW5cE6uUsJwRY15rlVCNXW8DWXiLW0UHVT7fYkaZhacs6IOhAkEHt6E-QTiQA

Answer (score 0):

try withoutt `{}`

add type `string`

```
interface IComponent<P = {}> extends React.FC {
  custom?: {a: string, b: string};
}

const Page:IComponent<{text: string}> = (text:string) => (
  <>{text}</>
)

Page.custom = {a: '1', b: '2'}
```